# What does ClockDivision do, as opposed to the Prescaler for STM32 timers?

Tags: stm32, timer

I am using an STM32 board (F7 series), and am looking through the HAL API documentation.  When I initialize a timer, I see two values, `Prescaler` and `ClockDivision`.  Now I understand that the `Prescaler` is used to divide the frequency of the clock.  However, what is the `ClockDivision` supposed to do?  I see it has three possible values, `DIV1`, `DIV2`, and `DIV4`.

My auto-generated code says the following.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have found a prescaler and a master PLL in the STM32 user guide, but no mention of a divider, which maybe external to the MPU. We need the HAL chart or image to know what your taking about.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the code with the `ClockDivision`.  I tried to make the code into a code block instead of pasting an image, but it doesn't seem to be formatting correctly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a big assumption that everything below holds true or at least be similar to F7 series description. I could be completely wrong! Please double check!

According to the stm32 [F4 family datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/3d/6d/5a/66/b4/99/40/d4/DM00031020.pdf/files/DM00031020.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00031020.pdf) register description, the "ClockDivision" stands for

> CKD:
> This bit-field indicates the division ratio between the timer clock (CK_INT) frequency and the
> dead-time and sampling clock (tDTS)used by the dead-time generators and the digital filters
> (ETR, TIx),
>
> 00: tDTS=tCK_INT
>
> 01: tDTS=2*tCK_INT
>
> 10: tDTS=4*tCK_INT
>
> 11: Reserved, do not program this value

I could not find any specific documentation related to F7 series and I am not quite aware of dead-time generators usage but ETR stands for "External Trigger Input".

Beware TIM1 is a special Timer, the same description do not hold true for other general pupose timers(ex. TIM2 etc.)

Also, HAL API Documentation is particularly not useful as it is just an accumulation of all the HAL Library comments without any description. If you are still interested, [this](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/2f/71/ba/b8/75/54/47/cf/DM00105879.pdf/files/DM00105879.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00105879.pdf) might be helpful for you.

Comment: It is the same description for the TIM1/TIM8 of the F7. See [STM32F7 ref manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/c5/cf/ef/52/c0/f1/4b/fa/DM00124865.pdf/files/DM00124865.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00124865.pdf) chapters 22.4.1. For the other timers, it is almost the same description, but mentioning only the digital filters, not the dead-time generator (see chapters 23.4.1, 24.4.1, 24.5.1).

Comment: Similar question and discussion, linked for posterity: https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000B42Wh5/timx-clock-division-configuration